# Built-in Symbol.asyncIterator in Array

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous

According to MDN Web Docs:

> There are currently no built-in JavaScript objects that have the [Symbol.asyncIterator] key set by default.

My question is how come this is working:

```
function promises() {
    return [
        new Promise(x => setTimeout(() => x(1), 1000)),
        new Promise(x => setTimeout(() => x(2), 2000)),
        new Promise(x => setTimeout(() => x(3), 3000)),
    ]
}

for await (x of promises()) console.log(x)
```

Comment: `for await` falls back to a synchronous iterator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MDN also states that

> *The `for await...of` statement creates a loop iterating over async iterable objects **as well as on sync iterables, including: built-in String, Array, Array-like objects (e.g., arguments or NodeList), TypedArray, Map, Set, and user-defined async/sync iterables*** - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) (emphasis mine)

Comment: Stupid mistake, I didn't notice the words "by default"

Comment: `by default` makes no difference

Comment: There's no object that comes with "asyncIterator" by default, but if you use "for await", "asyncIterator' is created.

Comment: @RafiHenig - oh, I don't see where that is documented

Comment: Because "asyncIterator" must be used in order to run the code above,
and if it's not there by default then it must be created some how.